# Parent View leaving space at top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios8, storyboard

[image: You can find the space at the top (almost at the place of status bar).]

This is the pic of my view controller. You can find the space at the top (almost at the place of status bar) in the screen shot. This is happening only on running the app in **iOS 8 versions**, not on **iOS 7 versions**.   Once I touch the screen It becomes normal.

Please refer the screen shot below:

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide the sample code for the ViewController. 

Without even looking at the code (that isn't provided), you may want to check your Status Bar style settings. I think the issue may be there.

Comment: The issue was due to UIPageViewController that am using in the controller (i.e.) the frame that has been set for it, is not working in iOS 8 version. The Frame goes like self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height). I just added 0.1 to the height, now its working fine as if in iOS7. Yet am not sure how this fix has got worked. And what is behind it.